# catching all signals in linux

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm trying to write a process in C/linux that ignores the SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals and exits for the SIGTERM. For the other signals it should write out the signal and the time. I'm having trouble cathing all the signals because i'm familiar only with catching 1 signal. If anyone could help me with this I'd appreciate it very much. Here is my code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int done = 0;

void term(int signum)
{
    if (signum == 15)
    {   
        //printf("%d\n",signum);        
        printf("Received SIGTERM, exiting ... \n");
        done  = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        time_t mytime = time(0);
        printf("%d: %s\n", signum, asctime(localtime(&mytime)));
        printf("%d\n",signum);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    action.sa_handler = term;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &action, NULL);
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);

    int loop = 0;
    while(!done)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }

    printf("done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you read http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html ? not all signals can be caught

Comment: Make a constant array if ints with all the signal numbers in it { SIGxxx, SIGyyy, ...} and then loop over it.

Comment: `printf("Received SIGTERM, exiting ... \n");` and don't use printf from within a signal handler, it is not signal-safe.

Comment: @tristan yes but i could find how to catch all the signals ....

Comment: @bmargulies i don't have to write them each one once, but which one was sent, or i don't understand ur method with looping over the signals :P

Comment: The handler is called with a pointer to a structure that includes the signal #.

Comment: @spd92 Uh, you get which one was set in the `signum` parameter? It's not very clear what your problem here is. You should be able to use the same handler function for all of the ones you want to catch.

Comment: @millimoose that's the problem i would need to catch all of them ... the only solution is to add them separate? ...

Comment: @wildplasser thx for the tip :) ... anything about my problem?

Comment: @spd92 Well, yes. "Catch any and all signals" is a massively impractical requirement so I'm not surprised there isn't a standard function for it.

Comment: @millimoose thx for the help :) i will do them manually then :D

Comment: At least you should declare the `done` flag as `volatile int done;`, or it might get optimised away in the polling loop. And the signal handler should NOT use printf(). period. It could set global flags or write to a pipe (this could block) or socket (preferrably UDP).

Comment: How about something like a combination of sigfillset() and sigismember()?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the easy way

```
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
  if (signo == SIGINT)
    printf("received SIGINT\n");
}   

int main(void)
{
       if (signal(SIGINT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
```

and so on.

signal() and sighandler() is the least complicated way to do this.

Call signal for each signal that you want to catch.  But as some have said  earlier you can only catch certain signals. Best to have a way to gracefully shut the program down.