# SIGINT handler cannot set property

Tags: linux, sigint

I am developing on a Linux-based platform.  I have implemented a sighandler so that when the program is terminated by Ctrl+C, it will exit gracefully. My definition of graceful is that it should close the UART port and set a system property. Currently, I see it close the UART but fail to set the system property. Below is an excerpt of the code.

```
#include <signal.h>
static sighandler_t sighandler_old;

int hUart = NULL;
volatile bool flag_stop_capture = false;

int set_uart_ownership_to_my_function(){
  /* Use persistent bit to tell system I have the UART */
  return property_set(PROPERTY_UART_OWNERSHIP, PROPERTY_UART_OWNERSHIP_TO_MY_FUNCTION);
}

int unset_uart_ownership_from_my_function(){
  /* Use persistent bit to tell system PTI has released UART */
  return property_set(PROPERTY_UART_OWNERSHIP, PROPERTY_UART_OWNERSHIP_NOT_IN_USE);
}

void exit_handler(int signum){
  flag_stop_capture = true;
}

int main(){
  /* Register exit_handler as a SIGINT handler and save old handler */
  sighandler_old = signal(SIGINT, exit_handler);

  flag_stop_capture = false;
  set_uart_ownership_to_my_function();
  hUart = open("/dev/ttyS1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

  while(!flag_stop_capture){
    //do stuff. 
  }

  unset_uart_ownership_from_my_function();
  close(hUart);

  /* Restore the old sighandler */
  signal(SIGINT, sighandler_old);
  return 0;
}
```

So currently, when I Ctrl+C, I see hUart close successfully, but the property PROPERTY_UART_OWNERSHIP doesn't get reset.  I know the exit_handler is being handled because I see hUart close.  Why isn't the property being reset?  Is there a permission problem when I Ctrl+C?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "seeing" `hUart` close, but note that all files are closed anyway when your program exits.  So the fact that the file gets closed does not necessarily demonstrate that control gets beyond `while` loop.  You might want to insert some debugging printfs to better understand what is actually happening.

Comment: If this is embedded, can you put an LED with a resister on a spare I/O PIN and have a simple macro to toggle it as an indicator, or toggle a pin and check it with a meter so you can verify what gets executed by your code? I assume you've definitely carefully verified and confirmed: (1) That you CAN set the property from main. (2) The UART is getting opened properly? BTW: Generally when I'm working on embedded tools I hook up an LCD so I can send debug messages to it.

Comment: BTW: Who is the provider of the property_set() API? The OS? A custom library? Your code? Is it possible to look at the code or man pages to see if there are any caveats about use?

Comment: Also, set the property TWICE from main() to be *sure* it can be set and *changed* via property_set() alone, e.g. without needing to be explicitly removed with a some sort of clear or reset or erase function.

Comment: Generally be absolutely positive that everything really works, handles changes, and is robust, at least in the most basic sense under normal working conditions before throwing signals at it.

Comment: If that's a Raspberry PI running Linux, also check https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: I answered a similar question in this link.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618579/catching-all-signals-in-linux/35244186#35244186)

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the inputs. So by seeing hUart close, what I mean is in my kernel driver tty_close() or w/e I make the kernel function toggle a pin and I see it indeed toggle.  That being said, would Ctrl+C automatically invoke tty_close().  That would explain why I see the toggle but not the property reset. I don't think SIGINT is being caught anymore, even after I commented out everything inside the while loop.  Anyone have any idea what I may be missing? Am I registering the sighandler wrong?

Comment: It's not so much that Ctrl-C will invoke it; it's that when your process exits for any reason whatsoever (including being killed by SIGINT or any other signal), the kernel will close all its files, and that will result in `tty_close()` being called just as if the program had explicitly called `close(2)`.  So you really need to do some different tests to determine if the signal handler is working properly.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is when a signal arrives, the handler may in some cases be set back to the default `SIG_DFL`.  The precise rules on whether this happens are complicated, but if that's the case, then sending two SIGINTs (e.g. hitting Ctrl-C twice) would kill the process.  If you use `sigaction` instead of `signal` you can specify that this should not happen (by clearing the `SA_RESETHAND` flag).